# React Native + Storybook + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

I have react native project setup with the typescript & its working fine. All the stories are running on device. But the issue is that storybook server is not running.

have followed all the step of [Storybook for React Native](https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-react-native/) and stories are loaded properly on device. But when I run the command `storybook start` is producing error.

```
myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:254
                const idxQuery = identifier.indexOf("?");
                                            ^

TypeError: identifier.indexOf is not a function
    at Resolver.parse (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:254:31)
    at resolver.getHook.tapAsync (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ParsePlugin.js:16:28)
    at AsyncSeriesBailHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Resolver.doResolve (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:235:16)
    at resolver.getHook.tapAsync (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:34:13)
    at AsyncSeriesBailHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Resolver.doResolve (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:235:16)
    at resolver.getHook.tapAsync (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/AliasFieldPlugin.js:43:13)
    at AsyncSeriesBailHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Resolver.doResolve (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:235:16)
    at DescriptionFileUtils.loadDescriptionFile (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:38:14)
    at forEachBail (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFileUtils.js:51:12)
    at args (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14)
    at onJson (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFileUtils.js:42:5)
    at resolver.fileSystem.readJson (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFileUtils.js:19:6)
    at process.nextTick (myAPP_PATH/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:73:15)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MyProject@0.0.3 storybook: `storybook start "start"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MyProject@0.0.3 storybook script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     xyz/2019-01-12T06_39_40_736Z-debug.log
```